# Connecting to MySQL Database with Code Hosted Locally

Tags: php, mysql, macos, database-connection, localhost

When I try to run working php code on my localhost instead of the web server, I am getting a connection error.

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: [2002] Connection refused
```

Any idea how to get the MySQL username, db, and password to work from my local machine?  I am using OS X Mountain Lion and Apache.

Do I have to login to the database server and add my IP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you've changed the default password root is allowed to connect to localhost, so that would be something like this :

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "database", 3306);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
?>
```

You can replace localhost by an ip, depends on how your database is configured to allow connections, using localhost or an explicit ip.

Answer (score 0):

in case you have downloaded the code from a server and are trying to make a local replica then you need to update the connection parameters to match your local configuration. You need to update username, password , database etc. as per your local settings.. Hostname you may keep as `localhost`

Respond back if things are not working and add more detail on how things started like how you set up the code locally..and what things you have tried yet..